# I Want Navigate the another Screen With DataSource

Tags: react-native, api, axios

[image]

When I am Click The Button Its Get Record Is It Ok. But I Want To Navigate Test Form With
React Navigation Stack And DataSource. Please Help Me To Issue That Problem

Comment: post actual code instead of just a screenshot, it will be easier for reproducing the problem and providing the exact answer.